# Rotating a cube using jBullet collisions

Tags: java, physics, rotation, lwjgl, bullet-physics

How would one go about rotating/flipping a cube with the physics of jBullet?

Here is my Draw method for my cube object:

```
    public void  Draw() {   
    // center point posX, posY, posZ
    float radius = .25f;//size / 2;

    glPushMatrix();
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        //top
        {
            glColor3f(5.0f,1.0f,5.0f); // white
            glVertex3f(posX + radius, posY + radius, posZ - radius);
            glVertex3f(posX - radius, posY + radius, posZ - radius);
            glVertex3f(posX - radius, posY + radius, posZ + radius);
            glVertex3f(posX + radius, posY + radius, posZ + radius);
        }

        //bottom
        {
            glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,0.0f); // ?? color
            glVertex3f(posX + radius, posY - radius, posZ + radius);
            glVertex3f(posX - radius, posY - radius, posZ + radius);
            glVertex3f(posX - radius, posY - radius, posZ - radius);
            glVertex3f(posX + radius, posY - radius, posZ - radius);
        }

        //right side
        {
            glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,1.0f); // ?? color
            glVertex3f(posX + radius, posY + radius, posZ + radius);
            glVertex3f(posX + radius, posY - radius, posZ + radius);
            glVertex3f(posX + radius, posY - radius, posZ - radius);
            glVertex3f(posX + radius, posY + radius, posZ - radius);
        }

        //left side
        {
            glColor3f(0.0f,1.0f,1.0f); // ?? color
            glVertex3f(posX - radius, posY + radius, posZ - radius);
            glVertex3f(posX - radius, posY - radius, posZ - radius);
            glVertex3f(posX - radius, posY - radius, posZ + radius);
            glVertex3f(posX - radius, posY + radius, posZ + radius);
        }

        //front side 
        {
            glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f); // blue 
            glVertex3f(posX + radius, posY + radius, posZ + radius);
            glVertex3f(posX - radius, posY + radius, posZ + radius);
            glVertex3f(posX - radius, posY - radius, posZ + radius);
            glVertex3f(posX + radius, posY - radius, posZ + radius);
        }

        //back side
        {
            glColor3f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f); // green
            glVertex3f(posX + radius, posY - radius, posZ - radius);
            glVertex3f(posX - radius, posY - radius, posZ - radius);
            glVertex3f(posX - radius, posY + radius, posZ - radius);
            glVertex3f(posX + radius, posY + radius, posZ - radius);
        }
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();

}
```

This is my update method for the cube position:

```
    public void Update() {
    Transform trans = new Transform();
    cubeRigidBody.getMotionState().getWorldTransform(trans);

    posX = trans.origin.x;
    posY = trans.origin.y;
    posZ = trans.origin.z;

    Quat4f outRot = new Quat4f();
    trans.getRotation(outRot);
    rotX = outRot.x;
    rotY = outRot.y;
    rotZ = outRot.z;
    rotW = outRot.w;
}
```

I am assuming I need to use glrotatef, but it does not seem to work at all when I try that..

this is how I have tried to rotate the cubes:

```
    GL11.glRotatef(rotW, rotX, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    GL11.glRotatef(rotW, 0.0f, rotY, 0.0f);
    GL11.glRotatef(rotW, 0.0f, 0.0f, rotZ);
```

Here is how I am getting the XYZ for the cubes from jBullet:

```
    public void Update() {
    //cubeTransform = new Transform();
    cubeRigidBody.getMotionState().getWorldTransform(cubeTransform);

    posX = cubeTransform.origin.x;
    posY = cubeTransform.origin.y;
    posZ = cubeTransform.origin.z;

    processTransformMatrix(cubeTransform);
}
```

Comment: Remember that when using `glRotate` you need to rotate **first** then draw, then `glRotate` back to neutral. OpenGL rotate, translate and scale all set OpenGL into a state so that everything after that is drawn with that rotation, translation and scale.

Comment: that explains why everything was bouncing around oddly.. :/ blah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing quaternions with euler angles. You would need to do a [conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles) to make it work. Instead of rotations around specific axis, I recommend to use the transformation matrix from Bullet physics directly. This includes the position as well.

```
// These can be pre-allocated.
float[] matrix = new float[16];
Transform transform = new Transform();
FloatBuffer transformationBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);

// Get the transformation matrix from JBullet.
MotionState motionState = rigidBody.getMotionState();
motionState.getWorldTransform(transform);
transform.getOpenGLMatrix(matrix);

// Put the transformation matrix into a FloatBuffer.
transformBuffer.clear();
transformBuffer.put(transformation);
transformBuffer.flip();

GL11.glPushMatrix(); // Save the current OpenGL transformation
GL11.glMultMatrix(transformationBuffer); // Apply the object transformation 
renderObject();
GL11.glPopMatrix(); // Restore the saved transformation
```

Comment: I really like this way of handling the rotations, but how would one go about reseting the glMultMatrix back to neutral?  I have tried a few methods such as: transformationBuffer.clear(); glMultMatrix(transformationBuffer);.  I have also tried to use transformationBuffer.reset();/transformationBuffer.rewind();

Comment: Here is what happens when I implemented the above: http://i1059.photobucket.com/albums/t428/superken81/aftermatrixflip.png

Comment: This is what the scene looks like prior to the above implementation: http://i1059.photobucket.com/albums/t428/superken81/beforematrixflip.png

Comment: Use GL11.glPushMatrix(); to save the matrix state and GL11.glPopMatrix(); to restore it after rendering the cube.

Comment: The screenshot looks like some scaling problem, no idea what is causing it. If that is the case, you could also create a matrix from a quaternion to get just the rotation matrix and use that for glMultMatrix. You also might need to transpose the matrix before passing to OpenGL, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Thanks msell!  I will look in transposing it, or investigating if it is a scaling issue.

Comment: no luck so far on trying to Transpose the matrix, but I am still looking.  it appears that OpenGl has a function for this, but it does not appear to yet be available in LWJGL that I have found.

Comment: just tried the following and I get the same result :(

Comment: GL11.glTranslatef(cubeTransform.origin.x, cubeTransform.origin.y, cubeTransform.origin.z);
GL11.glRotatef(cubeQuaternion.w, cubeQuaternion.x, cubeQuaternion.y, cubeQuaternion.z);

Comment: I also read that I should * 360 on the cubeQuaternion.w, which I also tried, and that made things slightly worse lol

Comment: Updated my answer to include the saving and restoring of the transformation matrix. Are the objects rotated correctly with the code above? Is the scaling the only issue you have with this? How are you creating the JBullet geometry for the cube?

Comment: i updated my question with how I am getting the xyz of the cubes from jBullet, hopefully that is what you are looking for.  I actually am already utilizing the push/popmatrix in my draw method, however I moved things around to be more like your code and still had the same results.

Comment: I really appreciate your help and I feel it is probably a minor thing, I just cant seem to see why everything is off.  This is my first venture into coding with jBullet and it has been quite frustrating at times, but I am not going to give up.

Comment: My suggestion is to not get the positions at all from JBullet. Instead just use the getOpenGLMatrix, which gives you both position and orientation. Then my other question is what parameters are you passing to the constructor of BoxShape? Do they match with vertices you are creating? Would everything work correctly if you just scaled the visuals by 2?

Comment: I actually do get them from the getOpenGLMatrix:
  cubeRigidBody.getMotionState().getWorldTransform(cubeTransform);
  
  posX = cubeTransform.origin.x;
  posY = cubeTransform.origin.y;
  posZ = cubeTransform.origin.z;

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I am also already scaling by 2.

Comment: Currently the constructor is passed the XYZ from a loop that I do to create the test enviroment.

Comment: Cube arrayCube = new Cube(blockX, blockHeight, blockY, .5f);
     game_objects.add(arrayCube);
     world.addObject(arrayCube.getCubeRigidBody());

Comment: The given code should be enough for generic JBullet rendering with LWJGL. For more complete example code check the demo application within JBullet, especially GLShapeDrawer.drawOpenGL() and LwjglGL.drawCube().

Comment: I think the issue was that I was setting the location in my Draw method, I am going to change things up and I will let you know if that was the issue.  Thanks for your help msell!

Comment: that was it, your code above worked great when I removed the stuff I was doing to get the xyz!  Thanks Msell

Comment: Please use a chatroom for extended discussion.